# Independence With n-1 variables and n

Tags: probability-theory

Give an example of a sequence of n random variables {Xi}n
i=1 such that any n − 1

are independent, but all n together are not. Can you generalize this to an example where for k < n,

any set of k RVs are independent, but any set of k + 1 RVs are not?

What I thought was taking (n-1) connections to an "and" logical operator, and so if we take n-1 boolean numbers, then the final output is in-dependable but when taking n, so the logical operator can output 1 only if all n are "on".

But I think that I'm not in the right direction, can someone direct me here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_{n-1}$ be iid and uniformly distributed on $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-2\}$, and finally $X_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{n-1}$ reduced modul0 $n-1$. Any subcollection of $\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$ of size $n-1$ is iid (symmetry!), but the full collection is not. To see the final assertion, think of the natural sample space for $X_1,\ldots, X_{n-1}$, namely $\Omega=\{\omega=(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_{n-1}): \omega_k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-2\}\}$ with the probability $P$ measure giving weight $(n-1)^{-(n-1)}$ to each point of $\Omega$, and with $X_k(\omega)=\omega_k$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$.   If $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ were independent, then you would have
$$
P[\cap_{k=1}^n\{X_k=0\}]=\prod_{k=1}^n P[X_k=0]=(n-1)^{-n},
$$
whereas $P[A]\ge(n-1)^{-(n-1)}>(n-1)^{-n}$ for each non-empty  $A\subset\Omega$.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much, that was very helpful!